# How to get "What's here?" info from latitude and longitude?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

There's an option to right click in Google Maps in the browser and select "What's here?". The result is either a street address or a suburb etc. Is it possible to implement similar functionality in Android Google Maps API V2? Would be cool to add the result as a title to a marker. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an address, or nearby points of interest?  For the latter, see the Google Places API.  https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically "whats's here" return address detail related to that particular latitude and longitude. So for that you can use below code and yes it good to be add result to InfoWindowAdapter

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```